# Android SDK OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener double callback

Tags: android

Code:

```
public class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(PreferencesChanged);
    }

    SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener PreferencesChanged = new
                SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences,
                    String key) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "changed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
              }
            };
}
```

Answer: if any option was changed (one time clicked), the text appears two times :-/ It's normal? Do "OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener" send double callbacks? How i can prevent double callbacks?

Comment: Actually, I'm pretty sure this has something to do with the listener being registered multiple times due to the life-cycle of your activity.

Comment: Yep, if you register `onCreate`, you should unregister `onDestroy`.

Comment: I also faced this kind of same problem when using Telephony class. In that case I created a variable and saved it in a database and checked the value before executing any code. For ex you can create a variable and if its value is 0 execute Toast otheriwse set variables value to zero.

Comment: I agree with karaokyo comment. Please follow that.